# Different ways of powering off

Tags: gnome3, shutdown

I prefer getting things done using the keyboard instead of the mouse. In Gnome to shutdown the PC, I have to click several times to shutdown my PC.

I prefer to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `poweroff`.

My question is: Do these two different methods perform the same actions and if not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do `ls -l /sbin/poweroff` I can see that `/sbin/poweroff` is only a symbolic link to `/bin/systemctl`. So there should be no difference (at least on my system).

**TIP:** I would do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> as I find it easier.

Comment: This is personal preference, e.g. I've become so used to CrunchBang's default keybinding of Super+x that I've set this to invoke the shutdown dialog on every system I've used since.

Comment: It surely is a personal preference.

Comment: Just adding a bit of info to the answer - GNOME uses systemd as a system manager. So, it makes no difference which way  you shutdown the machine. The end result is systemd is called to shutdown and it does whatever it has to, to shutdown gracefully. On SysVinit systems, there would be a difference and the preferred action should be shutting down from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't invoke the same actions, clicking the shutdown button will not insert the letters <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> etc in the buffer that you get when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or vice versa.

And although they will eventually most likely both call `shutdown (8)` to actually stop the machine, the commandline probably does fewer checks e.g. whether other users are logged in (on console windows e.g.)

Comment: GNOME uses systemd as a system manger. So, they will both invoke the same action of calling systemd to shutdown the machine. Systemd will do all the necessary checks while shutting down in both cases. Other than the letters being inserted in the buffer and shell history, the process will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the gnome way is more friendly with the desktop, and able to ask running applications to properly shutdown themselves, and even suspend the shutdown if critical ones are running, like VirtualBox, while the `poweroff` way cannot but kill existing applications.